# how to access class object attributes in python

Tags: python, oop, data-structures

so I have a method called **charge** that takes total as an argument. When I print out total `print(total)` it gives me `Price(currency='INR', excl_tax=Decimal('1000.00'), incl_tax=Decimal('1180.0000'), tax=Decimal('180.0000'))`. How do I access lets say incl_tax from this?

**views.py**

```py
class PaymentDetailsView(CorePaymentDetailsView):


    def handle_payment(self, order_number, total, **kwargs):

        razorpay_ref = Facade().charge(
            order_number,
            total,
            card=self.request.POST[RAZORPAY_TOKEN],
            description=self.payment_description(order_number, total, **kwargs),
            metadata=self.payment_metadata(order_number, total, **kwargs))

        source_type, __ = SourceType.objects.get_or_create(name=PAYMENT_METHOD_RAZORPAY)
        source = Source(
            source_type=source_type,
            currency=settings.RAZORPAY_CURRENCY,
            amount_allocated=total.incl_tax,
            amount_debited=total.incl_tax,
            reference=razorpay_ref)
        self.add_payment_source(source)

        self.add_payment_event(PAYMENT_EVENT_PURCHASE, total.incl_tax)
```

**facade.py**

```py
class Facade(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_friendly_decline_message(error):
        return 'The transaction was declined by your bank - please check your bankcard details and try again'

    @staticmethod
    def get_friendly_error_message(error):
        return 'An error occurred when communicating with the payment gateway.'

    def charge(self,
        order_number,
        total,
        card,
        currency=settings.STRIPE_CURRENCY,
        description=None,
        metadata=None,
        **kwargs):

        print("card")
        print(card)
        print("total")
        print(total)
        print(type(total))
        # print(getattr(self, 'incl_tax'))
        client = razorpay.Client(auth=("key", "pass"))
        client.payment.capture(card, total)
        return card
```

**prices.py**

```py
class TaxNotKnown(Exception):
    """
    Exception for when a tax-inclusive price is requested but we don't know
    what the tax applicable is (yet).
    """


class Price(object):
    """
    Simple price class that encapsulates a price and its tax information
    Attributes:
        incl_tax (Decimal): Price including taxes
        excl_tax (Decimal): Price excluding taxes
        tax (Decimal): Tax amount
        is_tax_known (bool): Whether tax is known
        currency (str): 3 character currency code
    """

    def __init__(self, currency, excl_tax, incl_tax=None, tax=None):
        self.currency = currency
        self.excl_tax = excl_tax
        if incl_tax is not None:
            self.incl_tax = incl_tax
            self.is_tax_known = True
        elif tax is not None:
            self.incl_tax = excl_tax + tax
            self.is_tax_known = True
        else:
            self.incl_tax = None
            self.is_tax_known = False

    def _get_tax(self):
        return self.incl_tax - self.excl_tax

    def _set_tax(self, value):
        self.incl_tax = self.excl_tax + value
        self.is_tax_known = True

    tax = property(_get_tax, _set_tax)

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.is_tax_known:
            return "%s(currency=%r, excl_tax=%r, incl_tax=%r, tax=%r)" % (
                self.__class__.__name__, self.currency, self.excl_tax,
                self.incl_tax, self.tax)
        return "%s(currency=%r, excl_tax=%r)" % (
            self.__class__.__name__, self.currency, self.excl_tax)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Two price objects are equal if currency, price.excl_tax and tax match.
        """
        return (self.currency == other.currency and
                self.excl_tax == other.excl_tax and
                self.incl_tax == other.incl_tax)
```

My goal is to extract incl_tax which is supposed to be an integer value, so I can pass it on to `client.payment.capture(card,total)`. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Where did you define `incl_tax`?

Comment: What I understand is total is a price object and incl_tax is a decimal field for it, so create a price object and using price.incl_tax find its value

Comment: incl_tax is defined in a class called Price in another file. However, my issue is with accessing this decimal field of  Price object in method charge.

Comment: @arajshree could you show me in code how to achieve this?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve], but you probably just want `total.incl_tax` ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Ok, so what isn't working? You can access an attribute on an object with the `.` operator, so like I said, you probably just want `total.incl_tax`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable" I get this error now! It's probably coming from client.payment.capture

Comment: That error gas nothing to do with your question. Please provide a [mcve] including the actual error you are encountering and the desired behavior. Likely, the client you are using requires the objects you pass to be json serializable. So maybe use a float (although if it is money then maybe a str)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that solves my problem. However, on a side note, the object `total.incl_tax` is of object type  ` <class 'decimal.Decimal'>`, typecasting it to str() or using json.dumps() isn't helping? Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the element in that list with the following, where 2 is the value for `incl_tax`:

`print(total[2])`